# Send all requests to a single controller based on a base route using Java Playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

Using the example below, I want all `service` requests (routes that begin with app/service) to be handled by the same controller. Is this possible using Java Play?

```
app/service/one
app/service/two/:param
```

The controller would then check the rest of the route and process the request accordingly.

**Edit 1:** The objective is to make sure I don't have to update the `routes` file every time a new route of type `service` needs to be added. So ideally, I'd just have a single `service` route in the routes file to handle all routes that begin with `service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why not?

```
app/service/one             controllers.Clients.one()
app/service/two/:param      controllers.Clients.two(param: String)
```

or

```
app/service/one             controllers.Clients.path(path = "one")
app/service/two/:param      controllers.Clients.path(path = "two", param: String)
```

or

```
app/service/:cat             controllers.Clients.path(cat = "one")
app/service/:cat/:param      controllers.Clients.path(cat: String, param: String)
```

or ... look ate the https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRouting

**Edit 1**

As similar as:

```
app/service/*path            controllers.Controller.handle(path)
```

Please read the details here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRouting#Dynamic-parts-spanning-several-/

Attention

> Note that dynamic parts spanning several / are not decoded by the router or encoded by the reverse router. It is your responsibility to validate the raw URI segment as you would for any user input. The reverse router simply does a string concatenation, so you will need to make sure the resulting path is valid, and does not, for example, contain multiple leading slashes or non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks but this requires me to list down all possible `service` route combinations in the routes file. I was looking for a catch all of sorts. Pls see my edit to the original question.

Comment: See my "Edit 1" as well